# How can i get a value generated by trigger (before insert) when i save an item?

Tags: spring, jpa

o/

I'm using Spring Boot on Gradle w/ JPA

I have the follow object: `{"id":123,"year":"123","name":"Xxxx","userKey": XXXXX}`

I will POST just "name" and "year" and the MySQL Trigger will generate the "userKey" BEFORE insert the data.

When i call `rep.saveAndFlush(object)` i will return the new object to the user WITH the userKey.

But its not happening! :/
When i send the POST `{ "name" : "Teste" , "year" : 30}`
The System returns `{"id":37,"year":"30","name":"Teste","userKey":null}`

If i try to get passing the ID as parameter, it returns `{"id":37,"year":"30","name":"Teste","userKey":"VVUR"}`

Why??

How can i return the object with your complete data??

I tried:

```
testeRepository.saveAndFlush(teste);
return new ResponseEntity<> (teste, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

&

```
testeRepository.saveAndFlush(teste);
testeRepository.flush(teste);
return new ResponseEntity<> (teste, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

&

```
testeRepository.saveAndFlush(teste);
testeRepository.flush(teste);
teste = testeRepository.findOne(teste.getId()); /* Same as GET */
return new ResponseEntity<> (teste, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

So.. isnt working yet! :( Just returns the ID and Null on userKey!

Comment: If you aren't going to force a refresh to fetch what was inserted, you need a mechanism for the databases to tell your provider/entity what was generated the similar to sequencing.   This is outside of the scope of JPA, so it will be provider/database specific, but some have feature you might be able to modify like EclipseLink's returning policy http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_returninsert.htm#CIHHEGJE

Comment: @NeilStockton i dont have .refresh() method on TesteRepository where i can found it?

Comment: It is on EntityManager, which is the most common class used in the JPA API, and since you tagged the question as "jpa" then I assume that Spring thing allows access to it. Note "Spring Data JPA API" != JPA API. I refer to JPA API

Comment: Yeah.. im using JPA API (i think :P) i've been added the Module to use it and just implemented "@Repository public interface TesteRepository extends JpaRepository<Teste, Integer> {}" following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1ydigiZ25g

Comment: My build.gradle have this line: `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')` so i think it is Spring Data JPA API.. I need to change to JPA API to use EntityManager.refresh()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With triggle, the data of managed object will not be synchronized with real data in the database (like in bulk update or bulk delete).
You can either refresh the object or clear the first level cache of the framework.

For Spring, i'm not sure about the solution, but may be you can use @CacheEvict and @Cacheable to workaround the problem.
For example:

```
  @CacheEvict(value = "teste", allEntries = true)
  public void resetAllEntries() {
    // Intentionally blank
  }

  @Cacheable(value="teste")
  public Teste update(Teste teste){
     return rep.saveAndFlush(teste);
   }
```

and the process will be:

```
 teste = update(teste);
 resetAllEntries();
 teste = findById(teste.getId());
```

Hope that this will help!